# atmega328p keeps resetting

Tags: avr, atmega, reset

i program my atmega with USBasp ,and i set the fuse bits hfuse:0xC9 and lfuse :0xff.
when i upload my simple code

```
int main(void)
   {
       DDRB |= 1<< PINB1 ;

       PORTB|= 1<<PINB1;
       while (1) 
            {


            }
  }
```

the MCU keeps resetting(led keeps blinking), i tried using usbasp as power supply and also i tried using 9v volt battery with regulator but still the same problem ( and i have 0.1uf capacitor between vcc and ground and pullup resistor in the reset pin).
i also bought a new atemga328p ( i thaught the other is dead) but always the same problem.

Comment: Is the watchdog (de-)activated?

Comment: thanks man , i changed hfuse to 0xD9 then reset it and it worked fine

Comment: @Janka your comment was spot-on. Perhaps you could post an answer so that OP can choose whether to accept it

Comment: It was a lucky guess … nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is set to set hfuse to hfuse:0xD9 instead of 0xC9 , to unprogram the watchdog